# Вложенность subscribe Angular6

Tags: javascript, angular2, typescript, angular, rxjs

Всем привет подскажите как правильно избавится от вложенности subscribe в angular 6

```
firstMethod(id: number): Observable<any> {

   return this.http.get<any>('URL');
}

secondMethod(id: number): Observable<any> {

   return this.http.get<any>('URL');
}

 myServices.firstMethod(id).suscribe(firstMethodRes => {
    myServices.secondMethod(firstMethodRes.params).subscribe(secondMethodRes => {

    ...

    });
});
```

Comment: [довольно неплохой материал](https://blog.angularindepth.com/learn-to-combine-rxjs-sequences-with-super-intuitive-interactive-diagrams-20fce8e6511)  по вопросу  как работают операторы в rxjs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используя `Promise`:

```
myServices.firstMethod(id).toPromise().then(({ params }) => {
    return myServices.secondMethod(params).toPromise();
}).then((secondMethodRes) => {
    console.log(secondMethodRes);
});
```

Используя `mergeMap || switchMap || concatMap || exhaustMap`:

```
import { mergeMap, switchMap, concatMap, exhaustMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

myServices.firstMethod(id).pipe(
    mergeMap(({ params }) => myServices.secondMethod(params))
    // ИЛИ
    switchMap(({ params }) => myServices.secondMethod(params))
    // ИЛИ
    concatMap(({ params }) => myServices.secondMethod(params))
    // ИЛИ
    exhaustMap(({ params }) => myServices.secondMethod(params))
).subscribe((secondMethodRes) => {
    console.log(secondMethodRes);
});
```

Используя `map + mergeAll || switchAll || concatAll || exhaust`:

```
import { map, mergeAll } from 'rxjs/operators';

myServices.firstMethod(id).pipe(
    map(({ params }) => myServices.secondMethod(params)),
    mergeAll()
    // ИЛИ
    switchAll()
    // ИЛИ
    concatAll()
    // ИЛИ
    exhaust()
).subscribe((secondMethodRes) => {
    console.log(secondMethodRes);
});
```

Comment: Отличный ответ! Еще было бы неплохо разницу между `switchMap` и `mergeMap` описать.

Comment: Ну хотя бы тогда ссылочки на документацию))

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko если я не ошибаюсь то switchMap завершает предыдущий subscribe,  а mergeMap в свою очередь порождает для каждого запроса новый