# RxJS. Как вызвать цепочку Observable используя результат предыдущих вызовов?

Tags: angular2, typescript, angular, angular5, rxjs

Есть 2 метода на уровне сервиса, один из которых использует результат работы второго как параметр:

```
export class ApiService {
    ... HttpClient и все прочее ...

    getType(request): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.post('api/type', request)
    }

    getCategory(type): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.post('api/category', type)
    }
}
```

И есть третий метод на уровне крмпонента который должен возвращать `Observable` метода `getCategory`

```
searchCategory(serch): Observable<any> {
    this.apiService.getType(serch) // из него надо получить результат пусть type
    return this.apiService.getCategory(type) // и в качестве ответа отдать Observable второго метода
}
```

Проблема в том как достать результат `getType` не используя `subscribe()`. Дело в том, что компонент который в шаблоне использует `searchCategory`

```
<app-my-component
  [category]="searchCategory"
></app-my-component>
```

Ожидает что параметр `category` будет метод возвращающий именно `Observable`

Я RxJS наверняка есть такая возможность. Каким получить результат из `getType`?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Вложенность subscribe Angular6](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/893525/%d0%92%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-subscribe-angular6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю Вам подойтет [mergeMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/mergemap.html).

Там где необходмомо выбрать категории по типу добавляем `mergeMap`.

```
searchCategory(search): Observable<any> {
    return this.apiService.getType(search).pipe(
        mergeMap(
            res => this.apiService.getCategory(res) 
        )
}
```

А в копоненте делаем уже подписку

```
this.apiService.searchCategory(search).subscribe()
```

Comment: здесь нужен `switchMap` если это "поиск"

Comment: @overthesanity в чем разница?

Comment: @Pavel https://netbasal.com/understanding-mergemap-and-switchmap-in-rxjs-13cf9c57c885

Comment: @overthesanity switchMap  имеет особенность - отменять предыдущую подписку. И это может стать проблемой при аякс запросах.

Comment: @KostiantynOkhotnyk если человек работает с поиском - то отмена предыдущего запроса на поиск - как раз то что нужно, `mergeMap` работает с параллельными гонками данных и неизвестно какой ответ придет быстрее от сервера

Comment: @overthesanity а, ну так да, согласен с Вами. Просто такой моделью стараюсь по-возможности не пользоваться, потому что, отмена запроса на фронте за частую не отменяет его на бэке