# http запросы в цикле

Tags: angular

Есть цикл for в котором выполняются запросы. Но т.к. js - асинхронный язык, то данные приходят не по порядку: сначала выполняется следующий шаг цикла, а после приходят данные предыдущего запроса. Как сделать, чтобы следующий шаг цикла выполнялся только после прихода данных?

```
getHeroes(): Observable<Hero[]> {    
    return this.http.get(this.url + '/api/people').pipe(map((data) => {
        let size = Math.ceil(Object.values(data)[0]/Object.values(data)[3].length)

        for (let i = 1; i <= size; i++) {
            this.http.get(this.url + '/api/people/?page=' + i).subscribe(data => {
                for (let j = 0; j < Object.values(data)[3].length; j++) {
                    this.heroes.push(Object.values(data)[3][j])                 
                }                           
            })
        }
        return this.heroes
    }))
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Вроде как-то так должно быть. Код не проверял, может не работать.

```
getHeroes(): Observable<Hero[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.url + '/api/people')
           .pipe(
              flatMap(data => from(Math.ceil(Object.values(data)[0]/Object.values(data)[3].length))),
              map(data => data + 1),
              flatMap(data => this.http.get(this.url + '/api/people/?page=' + data)),
              map(data => {
                  const heroes: Hero[] = [];
                  for (let j = 0; j < Object.values(data)[3].length; j++) {
                      heroes.push(Object.values(data)[3][j])                 
                  }
                  return heroes;
              }),
              toArray()
           )
}
```

Comment: Не работает. Куча ошибок.

Comment: Попробуйте спросить у автора ответа тут: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/893525/%d0%92%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-subscribe-angular6. Я в rxjs не очень силён, вот если б вам на RxJava было надо, я б точно помог)